# Setting URL to use slug instead of ID

Tags: django

I want my URL to have slug instead of post ID in django

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from blog.views import( 
    blog_post_detail_view, 
    blog_post_list_view,
    blog_post_update_view,
    blog_post_delete_view,)

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', blog_post_list_view),
    path('<str:slug>/', blog_post_detail_view),
    path('<str:slug>/edit/', blog_post_update_view),
    path('<str:slug>/delete/', blog_post_delete_view), ] 

    models.py

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404
from .models import BlogPost


def blog_post_list_view(request):
    qs = BlogPost.objects.all()
    template_name = 'blog_post_list.html'
    context = {'object_list': qs}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def blog_post_create_view(request):
    template_name = 'blog_post_create.html'
    context = {'form': None}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def blog_post_detail_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog_post_detail.html'
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def blog_post_update_view():
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog_post_update.html'
    context = {"object": obj, 'form': None}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

def blog_post_delete_view():
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog_post_delete.html'
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, template_name, context
```

)

I want the url to read http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/blogpost/i-need-this/change/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/blogpost/3/change/

Answer (score 0):

First things first you need to add slug field to you model and create an absolute url for the post_details model by the following:

```
 class BlogPost(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, max_length=40,unique_for_date='publish')


  from django.urls import reverse

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_details',args = [
        self.slug,
    ])
```

'blog' is your app name and  'post_details' is details view functions in your views.py file
Now include your app name to your urls.py file

```
 app_name = 'your-app-name'
```

change the urls path for details view

```
path('<slug:post>/',views.post_details, name = 'post_details'),
```

':post' is your finctions parameter.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by functions parameter

Comment: Here is your view for post details,
def blog_post_detail_view(request, slug):
slug is the positional argument in your functions. I have passed this as post.
you can edit this as:
def blog_post_detail_view(request, post):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=post)
And then the urls path should be '<slug:post/>'

Comment: Alright It's working now but yours too works. Thank you